# Convert array of nested Javascript objects into 2D array with unique keys-subkeys

Tags: json, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I want to convert an array of nested objects into a 2d array that I want to use as part of an apps script batchUpdate in Google Sheets.

I am using an object array as input, in apps script as below:

```js
[
  {
    a: "val1",
    b: {
      x: "val2",
      y: "val3",
      z: "val4"
    },
    c: {
      s: "val5",
      t: "val6",
      r: "val7"
    },
  },
  {
    a: "val8",
    b: {
      x: "val9",
      z: "val10"
    },
    c: {
      t: "val11",
      r: "val12"
    },
  },
  {
    a: "val13",
    b: {
      y: "val14"
    },
    c: {
      s: "val15",
      t: "val16",
      z: "val17"
    }
  }
]
```

so not all nested objects have all keys.

Since the number of objects is quite big, I am looking for an efficient way to process and **create a   2D array where the first column holds the unique keys, un-nested, and the sub-keys grouped together, while each further column holds the values of each object (where there is a key-value pair). Like the table below**:

| Key_subkey | Object 1 values | Object 2 values | Object 3 values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | val1 | val8 | val13 |
| b_x | val2 | val9 |  |
| b_y | val3 |  | val14 |
| b_z | val4 | val10 |  |
| c_s | val5 |  | val15 |
| c_t | val6 | val11 | val16 |
| c_r | val7 | val12 |  |
| c_z |  |  | val17 |

I am seeking to avoid nested for-loops to populate the array as it would be inefficient.

Any ideas on how to do that fast and concisely?

TIA

Comment: I think that your `the JSON objects` is an incomplete JSON object. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your sample value. How about this? By the way, can I ask you about the relationship between your data and column "A" of the table?

Comment: Hi Tanaike, thank you for getting back to me. 
Column A should contain the un-nested keys i.e. b:{x:val}, becomes b.x:val. The sample I posted is essentially, after I have parsed it into a Javascript object

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. I have to admit my Javascript skills are poor, so most probably it's not your English, but my JS skills to blame. So, trying to explain myself better, I have an array of objects where some of these object have nested objects as values, like {a:val1, b:{x:val2,y:val3}},  {a:val8, b:{z:val9}]. I want to create a list of all the unique keys-subkeys, i.e. { a, b-x.b-y, b-z} which will be in column A of a sheet. Then in column B to transpose the values of the first object in the array based on the key-subkey, column C for the second object etc.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I apologize for my poor English skill again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand the logic for obtaining your expected result. But, I would like to try to understand it. I really apologize for my poor English skill again.

Comment: My apologies for not being clear Tanaike. As an example, let's assume the table in the initial post is a sheet. The value of cell A4 is b-z and cell C4 is "val10".  Column C corresponds to all values of object 2 in the object array. Within this second object of the array, "val10"  has a key b:{x:val9,z:val:10} as you can observe in the initial question. Hope this makes it a bit clearer?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that your `the JSON objects` is an incomplete JSON object. By this, I'm confused to think about the logic for obtaining your expected result. I apologize for this. Is your showing `the JSON objects` correct data? From your reply, I'm worried that your showing data might be different from your actual data.

Comment: I used a sample to make it easier, without pasting lengthy objects. The data are coming from tradingView and are like, but much larger: {
        "symbol": "BTCUSD",
        "interval": "1d",
        "summary":
        {
            "RECOMMENDATION": "BUY",
            "BUY": 15,
            "SELL": 3,
            "NEUTRAL": 8
        },
        "oscillators":
        {
            "RECOMMENDATION": "NEUTRAL",
            "COMPUTE":
            {
                "RSI": "SELL",
                "STOCH.K": "NEUTRAL"
            }
        }, can I share a google doc?

Comment: I also made some edits to my initial post so hopefully it's a bit clearer? If sharing a file is an option I can share the whole API output as well

Comment: Thank you for replying. I would like to try to understand the logic for obtaining your expected result. When I could correctly understand it, I would like to think of a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Thank you Tanaike. Perhaps mentioning JSON has complicated things. I have edited the initial question to show that the input is an array of Javascript objects. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have an array of objects.. each object is a column and its properties are expected to have an expanded id (when flattened) as the composition of parent ids till root element.

So that the resulting object is a mapping of full expanded ids and their list of values as an array with slots position mapped to the corresponding column.

It's easier to show than to explain...

so here's there's the `fillBag` function that will iterate over the passed object properties (recursively) while filling the passed `bag` object that will hold the final result:

```
//this function is fully commented in the live snippet
function fillBag(prefix, colIndex, obj, bag){ 
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value])=>{              
        const index = `${prefix}${key}`;              
        if(typeof(value) === 'string' || value instanceof String){                
            const values = (index in bag) ? bag[index] : bag[index] = [];
            values.length = colIndex;
            values.push(value);                                
        }else{        
            fillBag(index, colIndex, value, bag);
        }
    });
}
```

I used your same input array but I had to make some corrections because you had some syntax errors missing closing `}`.

This is the final object returned:

```
{
  "a": [ "val1", "val8", "val13" ],
  "bx": [ "val2", "val9", undefined],
  "by": [ "val3", undefined, "val14" ],
  "bz": [ "val4", "val10", undefined ]
  "cs": [ "val5", undefined, "val15" ],
  "ct": [ "val6", "val11", "val16" ],
  "cr": [ "val7", "val12", undefined ],
  "cz": [ undefined, undefined, "val17" ]
}
```

if you needed an array of arrays instead of an object mapping unique keys to array values, you can also use `Object.entries` on top of that:

```
Object.entries($bag) //...[ key, [values] ]
```

***Warning*** it now takes into account the fact that later columns may stack up and if a given index doesn't show up anymore, the array of values for that index wwould not contain undefined values for the indexes following the last column where the property name did its last appearance. To correct that behaviour, the resulting bag get visited one last time after the whole object was processed, and ALL the arrays resized with the size of the biggest one (number of total columns).

```
function fillTrailingEmptyColumns(obj, cols){
  Object.values(obj).forEach( values =>{
    values.length = cols;
  });  
}
```

### Sparse arrays and setting .length property

It's worth to say that since the values are stored in an array for each key, the array will contain undefined values for columns in which the given index didn't have any value.

It could be interesting to further read about sparse arrays and empty slot.

Most people will find very surprising that you can actually set the `Array.length` property

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Indexed_collections#sparse_arrays

```js
const data = [
  {
    a:"val1",
    b: {
      x:"val2",
      y:"val3",
      z:"val4"
    },
    c: {
      s:"val5",
      t:"val6",
      r:"val7"
    }
  },
  {
    a:"val8",
    b:{
      x:"val9",
      z:"val10"
    },
    c:{
      t:"val11",
      r:"val12"
    }
  },
  {    
    a:"val13",
    b:{
      y:"val14"
    },
    c:{
      s:"val15",
      t:"val16",
      z:"val17"
    }
  }
]

const bag = {};

//fills the bag with key->values
data.forEach( (obj, i) => fillBag('', i, obj, bag));

//this is an information I could grab from data.length as well
const cols = findMaxColumns(bag);

//fills the trailing missing columns in bag for each key
fillTrailingEmptyColumns(bag, cols);

console.log(bag);

//returns the maximum number of columns descrived in the obj
function findMaxColumns(obj){
  return Object.values(obj).reduce(
    (max, value)=>{
      if(value.length > max)
        return value.length;
      else
        return max;        
    },
    0
  );
}

function fillTrailingEmptyColumns(obj, cols){
  Object.values(obj).forEach( values =>{
    values.length = cols;
  });  
}

//fills the bag object with values coming from obj at the given prefix and colIndex
function fillBag(prefix, colIndex, obj, bag){

  //for each entry in obj (an entry is key-value property pair)
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(
    ([key, value])=>{      
      //current index based on prefix
      const index = `${prefix}${key}`;
      
      //if the current property value is a string
      if(typeof(value) === 'string' || value instanceof String){        
        //if composed key exists in bag
        if(index in bag){          
          let values = bag[index];      
          //change the size of values in the array based on the current column
          values.length = colIndex;
          //push the current value in the array of values for this key
          values.push(value);
        }
        //else if composed key doesn't exist yet in bag
        else{
          //create a new array filled with nulls until now          
          let values = [];
          //change the size of values in the array based on the current column
          values.length = colIndex;
          //push the current value in the array of values for this key
          values.push(value);
          //sets the key in the bag for its first time
          bag[index] = values;
        }
      }
      //else if the obj is not a string (thus a nested properties bag)
      else{
        //recursively call fillBag with the current composed index and passing the current value
        fillBag(index, colIndex, value, bag);
      }
    });
    
}
```

Comment: @user2852591 I used an object as result matching the "table" expectation. Feel free to drop a comment if something was missed or if there's something wrong or I made invalid assumptions

Comment: Many Thanks!!! You got the idea exactly right! I tested it on the actual data and the bag gets full really nicely :) I was thinking something along the lines of sparse arrays but as my javascript knowledge is really basic I couldn't wrap my head around doing it like this. As the next step for me is to create the request array for batchUpdate, any pointers on how to efficiently traverse the structure and populate the request array?

Comment: It's hard to answer in general.. but I really think that every single javascript developer should learn this by hearth https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

Comment: I've been using javascript since its first day... and it's awkward saying that it took me long time to find out that you can set the length property of an array... that's quite huge and that's why I highlighted that spot in my answer. It didn't catch much interest.. maybe it's not so interesting as I thought or maybe it's just too far from the head and gets lost. Anyway glad it helped

Comment: it definitely helped. Coming mostly from the C world, there are too many aspects of JS I can't get accustomed to... Many Thanks again for the really elegant solution!